# Имена столбцов numpy

Tags: python, numpy, csv, обработка-данных

Как мне можно было бы получить имена столбцов моего структурированного массива numpy, взятого из csv-файла, в отдельный массив строковых переменных, для дальнейшей работы с ними.

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 3):

В Numpy никак, т.к. в Numpy матрице (`NDArray`) не существует такого понятия как имена столбцов - они имеют только порядковые номера от `0` до `N-1`.

Зато это можно сделать в Pandas DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(filename, sep=",")
columns = df.columns.to_list()
```